# How to get ALL member list in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command() 
async def members_info(ctx):    
    server_members = ctx.guild.members 
    data = "\n".join([member.name for member in server_members if "test" in member.roles])
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f'Участники сервера', description = f"{data}", color = discord.Color.purple())
```

Output just empty embed message with title and color without description
I dont know what i supposed to do -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you are missing the `members` intent. This means members are not loaded in cache unless you do a direct HTTP request. To enable:

First enable on [dev portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications):
[image: members intent]

Secondly subscribe in discord.py:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, ...)
```